# Change bootstrap column order randomly?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have several columns in in row. Is there a way to change their order randomly with jQuery when I refresh the page ?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">6</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">7</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">9</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do it randomly with pure HTML/CSS. You could probably do it with jQuery but not sure you'd want to.

Comment: Yes I would like to do it with query but I coouldn't find an example

Comment: Hello, i've added an example, please check.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to solve this in server-side code (if possible within your solution)?

Answer (score 1):

This one works :

```
$.fn.randomize = function(childElem) {
return this.each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var elems = $this.children(childElem);
elems.sort(function() { return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }); 
$this.remove(childElem);  
for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++)
$this.append(elems[i]);      
});    
}
$(".xcontainer").randomize(".column");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this. Since you haven't provided a sample code, or shown us your effort, i've prepared my own fiddle.

Check this snippet :

```js
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min and max values (inclusive)
 */
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

/**
 * Returns a uniquely generated random integer array, so we can use this as our order.
 */
function getRandomSequence(limit) {
  var arr = [];
  while (arr.length < limit) {
    var randomnumber = getRandomInt(0, limit - 1);
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == randomnumber) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
  }
  return arr;
}

/**
 * Shows randomly ordered columns in a container.
 */
function orderColumnsRandomly() {
  // Get the children of the container
  var columns = $("#xcontainer").children();

  // Empty the container.
  $("#xcontainer").html('');

  // Get a random sequence to show the columns
  var sequence = getRandomSequence(columns.length);

  // Loop through the column array with the given sequence and fill the container.
  for (var i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    $("#xcontainer").append($(columns[sequence[i]]));
  }
}

// Bind the button's click event.
$("#orderRandomly").click(orderColumnsRandomly);
```

```css
.column {
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.a {
  background: #c33
}
.b {
  background: #3c3
}
.c {
  background: #33c
}
.d {
  background: #3cc
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <button id="orderRandomly">Order!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row" id="xcontainer">
    <div class="column col-xs-3 a">a</div>
    <div class="column col-xs-3 b">b</div>
    <div class="column col-xs-3 c">c</div>
    <div class="column col-xs-3 d">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We simply generate an array of random integers, and using that random sequence, we fill our container with our divs.